# Is it possible to use one await keyword for resolving a set of sequential promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Perhaps this is a limitation of the language, but I am trying to figure out how I could get away with using a single `await` keyword for a set of sequential promise resolutions. I am trying to achieve something readable, like the following:

```js
const workoutExercises = await Workout.get(1).workoutExercises;
```

`Workout.get` accesses a database, and so returns a `Promise`. The promise resolves to an instance of `Workout`, which has a `get`ter method on the instance called `workoutExercises`, which is also a `Promise` that resolves to an array of `WorkoutExercise`s.

The above code does not work, and only waits for `Workout.get` to resolve; doesn't also wait for `.workoutExercises` to resolve. The following below code examples **DO** work, but I am trying to achieve a one-liner / more readability:

1:

```js
const workoutExercises = await (await Workout.get(1)).workoutExercises;
```

2:

```js
const workout = await Workout.get(1);
const workoutExercises = await workout.workoutExercises;
```

Edit #1
Updated the title and description to clarify that the problem doesn't revolve around the resolution of a Promise chain, but the resolution of a Promise based on the resolution of a preceding Promise.

`Workout.get --> <Promise> --> workout --> .workoutExercises --> <Promise> -> desired result`

Comment: if `Workout.get(1)` returns a Promise, then it wouldn't have a `.workoutExcercise` method ... it'd have `.then` and `.catch` - at least, that's how standard promises work

Comment: This isn't a chain of promises.  It's a promise that resolves to an object that has a property that is a getter that creates another promise when accessed.  That's not a promise chain by any definition.  The problem here is a poor interface for what you're trying to do.  You will have to use multiple `await` statements or multiple `.then()` handlers to deal with it.  If the syntax really bothers you, you can make a little helper function that does the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.then()` on the results of `.get(1)`, and extract `workoutExercises`. The one liner is very readable.

Example:

```js
(async() => {

  const Workout = {
    get: () => Promise.resolve({
      workoutExercises: Promise.resolve(3)
    })
  };

  const workoutExercises = await Workout.get(1).then(w => w.workoutExercises);

  console.log(workoutExercises)

})()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use one await keyword for resolving a set of sequential promises

Because these promises are not actually chained, it is not.  You have a promise that resolves to an object that has a property that when you access it has a getter that creates a new promise that resolves to the value you finally want.  That's two completely separate promises and you'll have to use `await` or `.then()` on each of the two so you can't do this with one single `await`.

You can use a little intervening code to chain them together and even put them into a helper function:

```
function getWorkoutExercises(n) {
    return Workout.get(n).then(workout => {
        // chain this promise to the previous one
        return workout.workoutExercises;   
    });
}

// usage
getWorkoutExercises(1).then(exercises => {
    console.log(exercises);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

or

```
// usage
try {
    let exercises = await getWorkoutExercises(1);
    console.log(exercises);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```